# Get confidence scores for Google Cloud Text to Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want to generate speech through Google Cloud's text-to-speech API but I'd also like to add a filter to it that filters out pieces of audio that do not meet a particular threshold score or confidence score. However the [Python client documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/texttospeech/latest) does not mention if such a method or attribute is available.

Is there a way that I can get any kind of scores for the audio files that I generate?